# About the symmetry of interaction matrix element in superconductivity

Tags: superconductivity, many-body

In *Sigrist, M. & Ueda, K. Phenomenological theory of unconventional superconductivity. Rev. Mod. Phys. 63, 239–311 (1991).* 
There is equation 2.1 write as below
$$H = \sum\limits_{{\bf{k}},{\bf{s}}} {\varepsilon \left( {\bf{k}} \right)a_{{\bf{ks}}}^\dagger {a_{{\bf{ks}}}} + \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{{\bf{k}},{\bf{k'}},{s_1},{s_2},{s_3},{s_4}} {{V_{{s_1},{s_2},{s_3},{s_4}}}\left( {{\bf{k}},{\bf{k'}}} \right)a_{ - {\bf{k}}{{\bf{s}}_1}}^\dagger a_{{\bf{k}}{{\bf{s}}_2}}^\dagger {a_{{\bf{k'}}{{\bf{s}}_3}}}{a_{ - {\bf{k'}}{{\bf{s}}_4}}}} } $$

and here 
$${V_{{s_1},{s_2},{s_3},{s_4}}}\left( {{\bf{k}},{\bf{k'}}} \right) = \left\langle { - {\bf{k}}{{\bf{s}}_1},{\bf{k}}{{\bf{s}}_2}} \right|\hat V\left| { - {\bf{k'}}{{\bf{s}}_3},{\bf{k'}}{{\bf{s}}_4}} \right\rangle $$

Then they say, this matrix element of V has symmetry below

$${V_{{s_1},{s_2},{s_3},{s_4}}}\left( {{\bf{k}},{\bf{k'}}} \right) =  - {V_{{s_2},{s_1},{s_3},{s_4}}}\left( { - {\bf{k}},{\bf{k'}}} \right) =  - {V_{{s_1},{s_2},{s_4},{s_3}}}\left( {{\bf{k}}, - {\bf{k'}}} \right) = {V_{{s_4},{s_3},{s_2},{s_1}}}\left( {{\bf{k'}},{\bf{k}}} \right)$$

I can somewhat prove this identities

For example, since summation over $k$ is equivalent to summation over $-k$, and also summation over $s_1$ is same as summation over $s_2$. So we have

$$\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{{\bf{k}},{\bf{k'}},{s_1},{s_2},{s_3},{s_4}} {{V_{{s_1},{s_2},{s_3},{s_4}}}\left( {{\bf{k}},{\bf{k'}}} \right)a_{ - {\bf{k}}{{\bf{s}}_1}}^\dagger a_{{\bf{k}}{{\bf{s}}_2}}^\dagger {a_{{\bf{k'}}{{\bf{s}}_3}}}{a_{ - {\bf{k'}}{{\bf{s}}_4}}}}  = \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{{\bf{k}},{\bf{k'}},{s_1},{s_2},{s_3},{s_4}} {{V_{{s_2},{s_1},{s_3},{s_4}}}\left( { - {\bf{k}},{\bf{k'}}} \right)a_{{\bf{k}}{{\bf{s}}_2}}^\dagger a_{ - {\bf{k}}{{\bf{s}}_1}}^\dagger {a_{{\bf{k'}}{{\bf{s}}_3}}}{a_{ - {\bf{k'}}{{\bf{s}}_4}}}} $$

Then we intentionally replace ${a_{ - {\bf{k}}{{\bf{s}}_2}}^\dagger a_{{\bf{k}}{{\bf{s}}_1}}^\dagger }$ by the equivalent $ - a_{{\bf{k}}{{\bf{s}}_1}}^\dagger a_{ - {\bf{k}}{{\bf{s}}_2}}^\dagger $, so we have
$$\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{{\bf{k}},{\bf{k'}},{s_1},{s_2},{s_3},{s_4}} {{V_{{s_1},{s_2},{s_3},{s_4}}}\left( {{\bf{k}},{\bf{k'}}} \right)a_{ - {\bf{k}}{{\bf{s}}_1}}^\dagger a_{{\bf{k}}{{\bf{s}}_2}}^\dagger {a_{{\bf{k'}}{{\bf{s}}_3}}}{a_{ - {\bf{k'}}{{\bf{s}}_4}}}}  = \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{{\bf{k}},{\bf{k'}},{s_1},{s_2},{s_3},{s_4}} { - {V_{{s_2},{s_1},{s_3},{s_4}}}\left( { - {\bf{k}},{\bf{k'}}} \right)a_{ - {\bf{k}}{{\bf{s}}_1}}^\dagger a_{{\bf{k}}{{\bf{s}}_2}}^\dagger {a_{{\bf{k'}}{{\bf{s}}_3}}}{a_{ - {\bf{k'}}{{\bf{s}}_4}}}} $$

so, term by term, it seems that we must have
$${V_{{s_1},{s_2},{s_3},{s_4}}}\left( {{\bf{k}},{\bf{k'}}} \right) =  - {V_{{s_2},{s_1},{s_3},{s_4}}}\left( { - {\bf{k}},{\bf{k'}}} \right)$$

But I have some doubt. If I start from the original definition of matrix element of V, I have
$${V_{{s_1},{s_2},{s_3},{s_4}}}\left( {{\bf{k}},{\bf{k'}}} \right) = \left\langle { - {\bf{k}}{{\bf{s}}_1},{\bf{k}}{{\bf{s}}_2}} \right|\hat V\left| { - {\bf{k'}}{{\bf{s}}_3},{\bf{k'}}{{\bf{s}}_4}} \right\rangle  = \left( {\int {{e^{i{\bf{k}}\left( {{{\bf{r}}_1} - {{\bf{r}}_2}} \right)}}V\left( {{{\bf{r}}_1} - {{\bf{r}}_2}} \right){e^{ - i{\bf{k'}}\left( {{{\bf{r}}_1} - {{\bf{r}}_2}} \right)}}d{{\bf{r}}_1}d{{\bf{r}}_2}} } \right)\left\langle {{s_1}} \right|\left. {{s_3}} \right\rangle \left\langle {{s_2}} \right|\left. {{s_4}} \right\rangle $$
and
$${V_{{s_2},{s_1},{s_3},{s_4}}}\left( { - {\bf{k}},{\bf{k'}}} \right) = \left\langle {{\bf{k}}{{\bf{s}}_2}, - {\bf{k}}{{\bf{s}}_1}} \right|\hat V\left| { - {\bf{k'}}{{\bf{s}}_3},{\bf{k'}}{{\bf{s}}_4}} \right\rangle  = \left( {\int {{e^{ - i{\bf{k}}\left( {{{\bf{r}}_1} - {{\bf{r}}_2}} \right)}}V\left( {{{\bf{r}}_1} - {{\bf{r}}_2}} \right){e^{ - i{\bf{k'}}\left( {{{\bf{r}}_1} - {{\bf{r}}_2}} \right)}}d{{\bf{r}}_1}d{{\bf{r}}_2}} } \right)\left\langle {{s_2}} \right|\left. {{s_3}} \right\rangle \left\langle {{s_1}} \right|\left. {{s_4}} \right\rangle $$
Note that in the above two equations, for simplicity, I assume that V doesn't filp spins.

So how could these two expression only be different by a minus sign? For simplest case, just look at the spin part, if ${s_1} = {s_3} =  \uparrow $ and ${s_2} = {s_4} =  \downarrow $, then
$$\eqalign{
  & \left\langle {{s_1}} \right|\left. {{s_3}} \right\rangle \left\langle {{s_2}} \right|\left. {{s_4}} \right\rangle  = 1  \cr 
  & \left\langle {{s_2}} \right|\left. {{s_3}} \right\rangle \left\langle {{s_1}} \right|\left. {{s_4}} \right\rangle  = 0 \cr} $$

Could someone help clear my confusion?